# Get Value of ID on Class Click in li tage

Tags: javascript, jquery

My result is `ui-id-1`. However, if want the `id` of anchor tag `ui-id-5` and others.

```js
$(".ui-corner-all").click(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 297px; left: 746px; width: 572px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kamran Khan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Muddassir</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Dr. M. A. al-mamun</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In that case you need to attach the event handler to the `a` elements, not the `ul`.

Comment: Do you want the id the li you clicked?

Comment: I can not able to change in html. the class of ul and li is same but i want to get the id of li not ul.

Comment: Your `li` have no `id`. As I said, select the `a` elements, not the `.ui-corner-all`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if you can write some code for me

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector you use to only apply to `a` elements

```
$("a.ui-corner-all").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

---

```js
$("a.ui-corner-all").click(function() {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="/*display:none*/top: 297px; left: 746px; width: 572px;">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kamran Khan</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Muddassir</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
    <a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Dr. M. A. al-mamun</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

So write jquery function for `li` click.

```
$("li").click(function () {
    alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `id` for `li` elements. Also to get the current jquery object, you need $(this) to use other jquery methods. You need to delegate the event from the `ul` to `li` and use `find` to find the `a` tag which has an id attribute

```js
$(".ui-corner-all li").click(function() {
  alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kamran Khan</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Muddassir</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Dr. M. A. al-mamun</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `this` refers to the actual clicked DOM node. So `this.id` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kamran Khan</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Muddassir</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Dr. M. A. al-mamun</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#ui-id-1").on('click', 'a', function () {
  alert($(this).find('a').attr('id'));
});
```

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Kamran Khan</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-6" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Muddassir</a></li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation"><a id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">Dr. M. A. al-mamun</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have to mark one answer as accepted among all. It's ok that you want to share your own answer. That's good.

Comment: this code will actually not work. You are trying to find `a` inside `a` since `this` will refer to the `a` that was clicked. `a` elements cannot be nested (*and your code does not nest them*) so this will always alert  `undefined`

Comment: @MuddassirIrahad  your code is not working at all:- https://jsfiddle.net/bvuxb1qy/

Comment: Agreed with @GabrielePetrioli